# How to pass html template as props to Vue component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a `textarea` component that include `html tag` and I want to get `html` in edit mode in this component. I use `Laravel` to generate html.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <textarea
                  :value="content"
                  :name="name"
                  :id="id">
              <slot></slot>
        </textarea>
    </div>
</template>
```

In blade page I used to this component:

```
<my-component>
   <p class="textbox">hello world</p>
</my-component>
```

when I put this component in page show me tag `<slot></slot>` in textarea. What should I do? Do you have any solution for my need?

thanks

Comment: Can you please explain more what you are trying to do? Are you trying to five the `<textarea>` a value from its parent? `<slot>` doesn't seem to work, but `:value` does work, and you already seem to be using it.

Comment: Looks you took a wrong solution to get some functionality (slot cannot be used inside textarea). As @rashad sugested, we need more detailed description of what you're trying to achieve to be able to suggest a proper solution.

Comment: There is a typo in my previous comment. Instead of "Are you trying to *five*..." It should be "Are you trying to *give*...".

Answer (score 12):

`<textarea>` components are treated as static by the Vue renderer, thus after they are put into the DOM, they don't change at all (so that's why if you inspect the DOM you'll see `<slot></slot>` inside your `<textarea>`).

But even it if they did change, that wouldn't help much. Just because HTML elements inside `<textarea>`s don't become their value. You have to set the `value` property of the [TextArea element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) to make it work.

Anyway, don't despair. It is doable, all you need to overcome the issues above is to bring a small helper component into play.

There are many possible ways to achieve this, two shown below. They differ basically in how you would want your original component's template to be.

### Solution: change `<textarea>` into `<textarea-slot>` component

Your component's template would now become:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <textarea-slot
                v-model="myContent"
                :name="name"
                :id="id">
            <slot></slot>
      </textarea-slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

As you can see, nothing but replacing `<textarea>` with `<textarea-slot>` changed. This is enough to overcome the static treatment Vue gives to `<textarea>`. The full implementation of `<textarea-slot>` is in the demo below.

### Alternative solution: keep `<textarea>` but get `<slot>`'s HTML via `<vnode-to-html>` component

The solution is to create a helper component (named `vnode-to-html` below) that would convert your slot's [VNodes](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/vdom/vnode.js) into HTML strings. You could then set such HTML strings as the `value` of your `<textarea>`. Your component's template would now become:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <vnode-to-html :vnode="$slots.default" @html="valForMyTextArea = $event" />
        <textarea
                  :value="valForMyTextArea"
                  :name="name"
                  :id="id">
        </textarea>
    </div>
</template>
```

### In both alternatives...

The usage of the `my-component` stays the same:

```
<my-component>
   <p class="textbox">hello world</p>
</my-component>
```

## Full working demo:

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  props: ["content", "name", "id"],
  template: `
      <div>
          <textarea-slot
                    v-model="myContent"
                    :name="name"
                    :id="id">
                <slot></slot>
          </textarea-slot>
          
          
          <vnode-to-html :vnode="$slots.default" @html="valueForMyTextArea = $event" />
          <textarea
                    :value="valueForMyTextArea"
                    :name="name"
                    :id="id">
          </textarea>
      </div>
  `,
  data() { return {valueForMyTextArea: '', myContent: null} }
});

Vue.component('textarea-slot', {
  props: ["value", "name", "id"],
  render: function(createElement) {
    return createElement("textarea",
      {attrs: {id: this.$props.id, name: this.$props.name}, on: {...this.$listeners, input: (e) => this.$emit('input', e.target.value)}, domProps: {"value": this.$props.value}},
      [createElement("template", {ref: "slotHtmlRef"}, this.$slots.default)]
    );
  },
  data() { return {defaultSlotHtml: null} },
  mounted() {
    this.$emit('input', [...this.$refs.slotHtmlRef.childNodes].map(n => n.outerHTML).join('\n'))
  }
});

Vue.component('vnode-to-html', {
  props: ['vnode'],
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement("template", [this.vnode]);
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$emit('html', [...this.$el.childNodes].map(n => n.outerHTML).join('\n'));
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component>
    <p class="textbox">hell
      o world1</p>

    <p class="textbox">hello world2</p>
  </my-component>
</div>
```

Breakdown:

- Vue parses the `<slot>`s into [`VNode`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/vdom/vnode.js)s and makes them available in the `this.$slots.SLOTNAME` property. The default slot, naturally, goes in `this.$slots.default`.
- So, in runtime, you have available to you what has been passed via `<slot>` (as VNodes in `this.$slots.default`). The challenge now becomes **how to convert those VNodes to HTML String?** This is a complicated, [still open, issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/10183), which may get a different solution in the future, but, even if it ever does, [it will most likely take a while](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9205#issuecomment-454261156).
- Both solutions above (`template-slot` and `vnode-to-html`) use Vue's render function to render the VNodes to the DOM, then picks up the rendered HTML.
- Since the supplied slots may have arbitrary HTML, we render the VNodes into an [HTML Template Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template), which doesn't execute any `<script>` tags.
- The difference between the two solutions is just how they "handle back" the HTML generated from the render function.

  - The `vnode-to-html` returns as an event that should be picked up by the parent (`my-component`) which uses the passed value to set a `data` property that will be set as `:value` of the `textarea`.
  - The `textarea-slot` declares itself a `<textarea>`, to the parent doesn't have to. It is a cleaner solution, but requires more care because you have to specify which properties you want to pass down to the `<textarea>` created inside `textarea-slot`.

## Wrapping up and off-the-shelf alternatives

However possible, it is important to know that Vue, when parsing the declared `<template>` into `<slot>`s, will strip some formatting information, like whitespaces between top-level components. Similarly, it strips `<script>` tags (because they are unsafe). These are caveats inherent to any solutions using `<slot>`s (presented here or not). So be aware.

Typical rich text editors for Vue, work around this problem altogether by using `v-model` (or `value`) attributes to pass the code into the components.

Well known examples include:

- vue-ace-editor: [**Demo/codepen here.**](https://codepen.io/jakob-e/pen/XMMxPm)
- [Vue Prism Editor](https://github.com/koca/vue-prism-editor): [**Demo here**](https://prism-editor.netlify.com/).
- [vue-monaco (the code editor that powers VS Code)](https://github.com/egoist/vue-monaco): [**demo here.**](https://jsfiddle.net/developit/bwgkr6uq/)
- [vue-codemirror](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-codemirror): [**Demo here.**](https://surmon-china.github.io/vue-codemirror/) This is by far the most starred on github.

They all have very good documentation in their websites (linked above), so it would be of little use for me to repeat them here, but just as an example, see how codemirror uses the `value` prop to pass the code:

```
<codemirror ref="myCm"
            :value="code" 
            :options="cmOptions"
            @ready="onCmReady"
            @focus="onCmFocus"
            @input="onCmCodeChange">
</codemirror>
```

So that's how they do it. Of course, if `<slot>`s - with its caveats - fit your use case, they can be used as well.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is **NOT POSSIBLE**

Your **slot** is put inside an **textarea** tag. Textare tag is only able to display the text content on its box.

So in the case you want a kind of "HTML edit mode", you may looking for an WYSIWYG editor, I recommend you can use CKEditor for VueJS, the editor even will allow you to direct edit HTML code

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/vuejs.html

Your HTML

```
<div id="app">
    <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="editorData" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
</div>
```

Your Component

```
const app = new Vue( {
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        editor: ClassicEditor,
        editorData: '<p>Editable Content HTML</p>',
        editorConfig: {
            // The configuration of the editor.
        }
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case if you want to write your own content editor you can use **div** with attribute contenteditable="true" rather than **textarea**. After this you can write your text decoration methods ...
The generated html with laravel store in *myhtml* and use it in vue component.

**Example:** I also uploaded to codesandbox  [[Simple Vue Editor]](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-d9msp?fontsize=14)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="getEditorCotent">Get Content</button>
    <button @click="setBold">Bold</button>
    <button @click="setItalic">Italic</button>
    <button @click="setUnderline">Underline</button>
    <button @click="setContent">Clear</button>
    <div class="myeditor" ref="myeditor" contenteditable v-html="myhtml" @input="onInput"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      myhtml:
        "<h1>Simple editor</h1><p  style='color:red'>in vue</p><p>Hello world</p>" // from laravel server via axios call
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(e) {
      // handle user input
      // e.target.innerHTML
    },
    getEditorCotent() {
      console.log(this.$refs.myeditor.innerHTML);
    },
    setBold() {
      document.execCommand("bold");
    },
    setItalic() {
      document.execCommand("italic");
    },
    setUnderline() {
      document.execCommand("underline");
    },
    setContent() {
      // that way set your html content
      this.myhtml = "<b>You cleared the editor content</b>";
    }
    // PS. Good luck!
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.myeditor {
  /* text-align: left; */
  border: 2px solid gray;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
}
</style>
```