# Capturing html wrapped by the component to set a data value in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on a tiptap based component. I want to take the html that is within the component tags

```html
<vue-wysiwyg>
    <p>Hey, this is some test text.</p>
    <p>I should end up in editor.content</p>
</vue-wysiwyg>
```

And have the editor.content data for my component be given it.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      editor: new Editor({
        content: '',
      }),
    }
  },
}
```

I thought about slots but that just passes through html, it doesn't capture it.

Comment: I think what you want is pretty much the same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58057169/1850609 I go into the caveats of what you want there, as well as what you can do about it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the slots are the way to go, but since they contain vdom objects we have to use vue to convert it into html. The following should work:

```
computed: {
    html(){

        return new Vue({ 
                render: h => h('div', {}, this.$slots.default)
            })
            .$mount().$el.innerHTML
    } 
}
```

We are creating simple component instance that has only a render function and than we `$mount` it to generate the DOM and than we extract the `innerHTML` from the root element.

*NOTE: You would have to import Vue in this file*

Answer (score 1):

You can give the component a `ref` and access its inner HTML and assign it `editor.content`

```html
<vue-wysiwyg ref="wysiwyg">
    <p>Hey, this is some test text.</p>
    <p>I should end up in editor.content</p>
</vue-wysiwyg>
```

And then in the mounted life cycle hook

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      editor: new Editor({
        content: '',
      }),
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.editor.content = this.$refs.wysiwyg.$el.innerHTML;
  }
}
```

[Like this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-1yvdo)

Hope this helps